# Calculating Formulas based on Alphabet using sql server procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 4 columns like below

```
Name          Alphabet     Formula     Value

Total1         A                        20    

Total2         B                        10

Total3         C             A+B        

Total4         D             C+A+B
```

-

I have the value for A and B and through Stored procedure how can i calculate the total3 and total 4 values i have known..

Comment: if this is a real world problem, i'd consider redesigning it. it's just going to bring a whole world of pain when the formulas start getting more complicated.

Comment: @havin Is there always `SUM` in formula?

Comment: No There is Subraction and multiplication involved.. Like it may be A+B-D  or A-B-C OR A X B XC

Comment: @tanner how can we do it..Can we do it in frond end like datatable..If it is in SP how can we plan it..

Comment: @havin Is there any data like this `(A + B) * C`?

Comment: @NEER there is data like (A + B) * C  or like (A + B) * 0.02

Comment: @havin I think You cant. You need a [stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack(v=vs.110).aspx) for mathematical expression.

Comment: Can you pls explain how to use stacks in this scenerio..Is it possible to calculate  cost based on formula..

Comment: @havin You cant this in sql. Check this [link](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci241/eval.htm)

Comment: i need to accomplish this  in stored procedure...Is it possible to use cursor..

Comment: If there is any solution..Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try using SUM inside stored procedure.

Add SUM(A+B) AS ABName, SUM(ABName + A + B) AS ABCName inside your query

See if it helps

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention the columns are generated dynamically not fixed columns..

Comment: Well it may work if you use another temporary table to store the previous data.. so you can get the last computation for your store proc

Comment: My problem is how does i recognize the formula value and add or subract or multiply accordingly..For Example if i take tempvalue for value A and corresponding formula ..How can i recognize the string types like +,-,* from  formula and calculate accordingly...

Comment: Declare a temporary variable for each select query. You might need to call the data for each temporary variable, for example: DECLARE @tmpVariable AS Int SELECT tmpVariable = YourField WHERE Condition = Condition (If Any) then insert the tmpVariable to your desire table

Comment: I used it mostly on FIXED columns but in your case, this should work. The only difference is mine are FIXED and your columns are generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DECLARE @ValueA as int
   DECLARE @Valueb as int

   select @ValueA=sum(value) from yourTable where alphabet='A'
   select @ValueB=sum(value) from yourTable where alphabet='B'

   update yourTable set value=@ValueA + @ValueB where alphabet='C'
```

Comment: Thanks ,the column is dynamically generated.It should get the alphabet value and related formula and calculate the cost..I guess your answer works best with fixed columns and values in table..

Comment: I mean column values are dynamically generated..Today 4 columns and tomorrow it would be like Total5   E      A+B-D